# iFrame visibility in vs2010 in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Is there any way to set the visibility of an iFrame dynamically?

Tried researching on the web but couldnt find any.

Answer (score 2):

You could add a `runat="server"` tag to the iframe:

```
<iframe src="..." id="myframe" runat="server"></iframe>
```

and then in your code behind you could access it my id and set properties:

```
myframe.Visible = False
```

Note that by setting its Visible property to False the iframe will not be rendered at all in the output HTML. If you wanted to hide the iframe on the client only you could manipulate its Attributes or Style properties.

Comment: Thanks so much it works.. I tried looking for the solution but not able to do so